# Not getting option to run xml file as testng suite

Tags: java, selenium, testing

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4qwq.png)

Hub is up and running and device are registered with hub.

But I am not getting option to run xml for parallel execution as Testng suite.

Can anybody please suggest what is missing.

Comment: Are you talking about 'Run' option for testng.xml or pom.xml?

Comment: problem got resolved by downloading eclipse from marketplace